# Register action on activation for every ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm doing tests for some of my controller's actions in WebAPI. I'm trying to configure Autofac so it will be one universal scope with settings for every test.

Everytime an `ApiController` is requested from Autofac I want to for instance create a ClaimsIdentity so the user authentication can be tested.

This is how I try to do it:

```
newBuilder.RegisterType<ApiController>().OnActivated(c =>
{
    var controller = c.Instance;
    controller.Request = Message;
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserId));
    controller.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
});

newBuilder.Update(container);
```

However this doesn't work. If I replace `ApiController` with any actual controller then it works.

My controllers are registered like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to do something like I described, although I'm not perfectly satisfied with the solution (but it works).

```
// Get any controller from the namespace where all the controllers are
var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserController));

foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.Namespace == "Namespace.With.Controllers" && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ApiController)))
    {
        newBuilder.RegisterType(type).OnActivated(c =>
        {
            var controller = (ApiController)c.Instance;
            controller.Request = Message;
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserId));
            controller.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        });
    }
}
```